# how does whatwg-fetch work with msw/node?

Tags: fetch, msw

I am using msw/node with my react-testing-library integration test.

When we mock fetch api with msw/node, we have to use polyfills for that since node does not support browser specific api such as localstorage, fetch.

[msw documentation](https://mswjs.io/docs/api/setup-server#limitations) also states that we have to use polyfills for unsupported features.

It seems that we can use whatwg-fetch for mocking fetch api in msw/node environment as [others suggest](https://github.com/mswjs/msw/issues/170).

But [whatwg-fetch](https://github.com/github/fetch#read-this-first) states that we cannot use them in node environment, and this is why I am confused.

Is this collision happening because msw/node's environment is not a native node environment? It seems that both jest and msw/node runs on node environment, and what makes msw/node environment enable to use whatwg-fetch available?

Thank you.